# Singly Linked List Implementation in C using 3 different typedefs

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So, my task is to to write a full implementation of a `Singly Linked List` in `C`.

I wrote before implementations of a `stack` and a `dynamic vector`, but this time, the linked list confuses me a little because of the use of 3 different `typedef`.

I'll be glad to get your review and tips on my code.

I would make a test file as I always do, but I am having a hard time of writing one because of all the `void *` casts .

I won't add all the 14 functions, i'll add just the functions that I'm least sure of.

So we must follow the following `typedefs` and the given `prototypes`. So neither of them can be changed.

I also had to add a **"dummy node"** as the last node, which means there will be always a **"dummy node"** that will indicate that the one before it, is the **"real"** last node in the list. This is part of the instructions.

```
typedef struct slist slist_ty;

typedef struct slist_node slist_node_ty;

typedef slist_node_ty *slist_iter_ty;
```

This is my implementation of the structs:
*They asked us to allow in theory any type of data in our nodes, that's why I wrote `void *`.*

```
struct slist
{
    slist_iter_ty head;
    slist_iter_ty end;
};

struct slist_node
{
    void *data;
    slist_iter_ty next;
};
```

And these are the functions:

```
/* Creates an empty single-linked list and returns pointer to the head */
/* returns NULL on failure*/
/* Complexity: O(1) */
slist_ty *SlistCreate(void)
{
    slist_ty *new_list = (slist_ty *)malloc(sizeof(slist_ty));
    if (NULL == new_list)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        return(NULL);
    }
    
    new_list->head = NULL;
    /* create a dummy node that will represent the end of the list */
    new_list->end = (slist_node *)malloc(sizeof(slist_node));
    if (NULL == new_list->end)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        free(new_list);
        return(NULL);
    }
    
    new_list->end->data = NULL;
    new_list->end->next = NULL;
    
    return(new_list->head);
}

/* Deletes entire List */
/* Complexity: O(n) */
void SlistDestroy(slist_ty *slist)
{
    slist_iter_ty temp = NULL;
    
    assert(slist);
    
    while(NULL != slist->head)
    {
        tmp = slist->head;
        slist->head = temp;
        free(temp);
    }
    
    free(slist->end);
    slist->end = NULL;
    
    free(slist);
    slist = NULL;
}

/* Insters the element after the iterator, returns iterator to the new node */
/* TODO Undefined behaviour if iter is slist_END */
/* Complexity: O(1) */
slist_iter_ty SlistInsert(slist_iter_ty iter, void *data)
{
    slist_iter_ty new_node = NULL;
    
    assert(iter);
    assert(iter->next);
    assert(data);
    
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = iter->next;
    iter->next = new_node;
    
    return(new_node);
}
    
    
    /* Returns iterator to end of the list */
    /* Complexity: O(1) */
    slist_iter_ty SlistIteratorEnd(const slist_ty *slist)
    {
        slist_iter_ty iterator = slist->head;
        
        assert (slist);
        
        if (NULL == slist->head)
        {
            return(NULL);
        }
        
        while (NULL != iterator->next->data)
        {
            iterator = iterator->next;
        }
        
        return(iterator);
    }
```

My question along the request to get a feedback is:

Should I `free` any new `slist_iter_ty` that I make ?
For example, I made an `iterator` of type `slist_iter_ty` in the last function, in order to help me to traverse the list. But I can't free the iterator because I need to return it as the return value.

I also made a `new_node` in the `SlistInsert`function.

Will it be freed as part of the `SlistDestroy` function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slist - is the list. when you create this list you use malloc so when you want to destroy it you need to free the list.

also - you used malloc every time you used insert. so when you want to destroy the list, you need to empty it from all the nodes - so you will need to free node by node

i can see you doesn't use mallloc in slist insert - how can you keep the data without use malloc?

**In destroy function**

```
 while(NULL != slist->head)
{
    tmp = slist->head;
    slist->head = temp;
    free(temp);
}
```

**I think what you meant is:**

```
while(NULL != slist->head)
{
    tmp = slist->head;
    slist->head = slist->head->next;
    free(tmp);
}
```

**In insert function**

```
slist_iter_ty new_node = NULL;
```

what you should write:

```
new_node = (slist_iter_ty) malloc(sizeof(slist_node));
```

**in slist end function**

```
slist_iter_ty SlistIteratorEnd(const slist_ty *slist)
```

**you can just return** (after you assert something :)) :

```
return (slist->end);
```

(otherwise it wouldent be O(1) it would be O(n))

Comment: I know that I need to `free` node by node, you can see my implementation for `SlistDestory`. My question was whether the implementation is correct?

Oh, you are right about the `Insert`. So I think the right move is to add `slist_iter_ty new_node = (slist_node *)malloc(sizeof(slist_node));` instead of `new_node = NULL` in the beginning of the function?

Comment: Thanks for all your help.
What about 
`slist->head = slist->head->next;` ? You wrote this, but in this way, I don't even need any `temp` variable? I mean I can just write this line.

Comment: No, if you free it you wouldn't be able to get to `head->next`. and if you get to `head->next` you will not be able to free it

Comment: Oh, gotcha! The one thing that can't reallty get is why we need to only free the `node` itself, without the need to free the data which located inside of it? I mean, the data is also stored on an allocated memory, so why we won't free it in every iteration?

Comment: P.S in the `slist end` function I can't just return the `slist->end` because it would return the `dummy node`.  I need to return the node that right before it ( I think ). But you are right, they said it should be `O(1)` but I don't get.. why would they want us to return the dummy node? it's not really the end of the list

Comment: you cant return the node before the dummy in O(1) complexity... and about the free - you need to free all your malloc so you need to free all nodes (you dont malloc the void* data you malloc the whole node. and after the list will be empty you will have to free the dummy node and the list itself

Comment: Of course lol, you don't even need to ask. Thanks a lot for all your help, I appreciate it!

So for all the rest, I guess it's fine ?

Comment: Hey @Asaf, why do I need to allocated memory for the node by my self, by the api side, in the `insert` func? You can see it receives a `slist_node_ty *` type, which means the user already passes to the function a created node with allocated memory for it, or doesn't he? I mean, I think maybe it's the user's job to allocated and create this node, pass it with the relevant data he wants inside that node, and the function will add both of them to the list.] without the need of allocating because it's already allocated by the user. So maybe I should have write `slist_iter_ty new_node = iter;` ?

Comment: `slist_iter_ty SlistInsert(slist_iter_ty iter, void *data)` - you get the iterator you want to insert the new node - this is not empty iterator (at least i don't think thats is - according to the api)

Comment: yeah, so what exactly should I do? Create a new node also in my func, allocate memory and give it the address of the node that is passed from the user?

Comment: Also, how should I implement the `remove` function? should I just `iter = iter->next;` ? or should I somehow save in `temp` the current `iter`. then `iter = iter->next;` and then `free(temp)`?

Comment: try it yourself :) if it wouldn't go well post new question with the new issue :) best of luck